# When using GregorianCalendar and adding 4 years, why does it appear further in date?

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I've completed this assignment and the output appears to work well except for the fact that my results for projGradDate or Graduation Date should be 4 years greater than the enrollment date.  Why does it appear as if it's more than 4 years or nearly 5 years?

My results after running the program are as follows

Enrollment date: 10/14/2013
Graduation date: 07/17/2018

This seems like almost 5 years or am I overlooking something?

Here is my code (first the CollegeStudent Class then the TestCollegeStudent Application):

```
this.fName = fName;
this.lName = lName;
this.enteredEnrollmentDate = enteredEnrollmentDate;
projGradDate = new GregorianCalendar(
        enteredEnrollmentDate.getInstance().get(enteredEnrollmentDate.YEAR),
        enteredEnrollmentDate.getInstance().get(enteredEnrollmentDate.MONTH),
        enteredEnrollmentDate.getInstance().get(enteredEnrollmentDate.DAY_OF_MONTH));
projGradDate.set(projGradDate.YEAR,  projGradDate.get(projGradDate.YEAR) + 4 );
```

Comment: I couldn't get all of the code formatted in so I posted the relevant code, projGradDate.get(projGradDate.Year) + 4).  I'm also having some difficulty understanding why you have GregorianCalendar requires  you to getInstance() first?  can anyone help explain?

Comment: With `Calendar` `getInstance()` will just give you a new object initialized to the current date and time. Can you show us the field definition of `enteredEnrollmentDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should start working when you remove the `.getInstance()`. Just tried it like this:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

/**
 * Created for http://stackoverflow.com/q/25353775/1266906
 */
public class AddToCalendar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GregorianCalendar enrollmentDate = new GregorianCalendar(2013, Calendar.OCTOBER, 10);
        GregorianCalendar graduationDate = new GregorianCalendar(enrollmentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                                                 enrollmentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                                                 enrollmentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        graduationDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 4);

        DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance();
        System.out.println(
                dateFormat.format(enrollmentDate.getTime()) + " -> " + dateFormat.format(graduationDate.getTime()));
    }
}
```